# How to export MYSQL Database tables from one server to another

Tags: mysql

How do I export and import MYSQL database selected tables(not all) from one machine to another machine ?

cheers

Answer (score 4):

mysqldump [options] db_name [tables] and then load them using mysql -u root -p < backup.sql

Or rsync /var/lib/mysql/ ...

Answer (score 0):

I use the [MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html), it lets you do backups/exports interactively to a file (& restore from a file). From a command-line, what @Aif said. If you are worried about atomicity / consistent database state, LOCK TABLES first and then UNLOCK TABLES afterward.